# Send cookies to next activity android

Tags: android, cookies, android-activity

I use httpclient along with cookiestore to keep my session, now I want to use the same session on the next activity, I'm using api 8 so I can't use cookiemanager. Is it possible? If only I could somehow send the cookie list through, eg:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
i.putExtra("domain", domain);
//need to get the following list across
List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
//i.putMyDamnCookies("cookies",cookies);
startActivity(i);
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store your List as an array of strings and pass it to in an intent to next activity like this:

```
String[] cookieArray = new String[cookies.size()];
            //copy your List of Strings into the Array 
            int i=0;
            for(Cookie c : cookies ){
                cookieArray[i]=c.toString();
                i++;
             }
            //then pass it in your intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            intent.putExtra("cookieArray", cookieArray);
            startActivity(i);
```

Then in your next actvity, retrieve the array of cookies from the intent and convert the cookies back like so:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = new List<Cookies>();
for(int i=0;i<cookieArray.size;i++)
{
cookies.add(new HttpCookie(cookieArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanx but once I sent it to the new activity, how do I convert from strings back to cookies?
And remember to put `i++;` in your for loop

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can send a `List` to another activity, but first you'll need to convert it to an instance of `ArrayList`, or `String[]` array.

Take a look over this threads:
[Passing a List to another Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087198/passing-a-list-to-another-activity-in-android)
[How to put a List in intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541088/how-to-put-a-list-in-intent)

Comment: Do you have any pointers to convert `List<Cookie>` to `List<String>` please?

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just read the cookie from the HTTP header, and store it however is convenient for you.

I think this is probably overkill, but here's an example that uses the Apache HTTP Client that ships with Android 2.2:

- [How do I make an http request using cookies on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678630/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-android)

Also look here (available since level 1):

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/package-summary.html