# sending and receiving Arraylist using intent? Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create a list of countries, that's to be added by the user during run time.

I'm using intent & adapter, and listview to show the countries.

When the activity start"MyCountries"the user click on the button add country, a new activity will start" Add Country", my question here is why I can't see any country on the list? i'm I sending and receiving correctly?
code for MyCountries:

```
public class MyCountries extends Activity {



private ListView lv;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String>list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_countries);

    //Button compute=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    list=new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    Intent i = getIntent();  

    list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("country&year");

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_countries, menu);
    return true;
}
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddCountry.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
```

code for "AddCountry"

```
public class AddCountry extends Activity {
private EditText name;
private EditText year;
public String country_name;
public int visited_year;
public ArrayList<String>arr;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_country);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);

    year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year);
    arr= new ArrayList<String>();
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
}



public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Add was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //new activity
        Intent sending = new Intent();

        country_name = name.getText().toString();
        visited_year = Integer.parseInt(year.getText().toString());

        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            arr.add(country_name+""+visited_year);
            //startActivity(sending);
        }
        sending.putStringArrayListExtra("country&year", arr);

    }
}
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); should be called after making some change to adapter not just the list

Comment: also make sure you are getting the values list from intent by logging its size or content

Comment: I'm not totally following the code.  I see how you start AddCountry from MyCountries, but I don't see how AddCountry returns to MyCountries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending empty list to adapter:

```
list=new ArrayList<String>();// empty list

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

// get data from intent(to your list) before initializing your adapter and you don't need to notify

```
  list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("country&year");

       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: ok so I need to write this line of code in between?                 list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("country&year");

Comment: if your list not coming from from another activity this post will be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087198/passing-a-list-to-another-activity-in-android

Comment: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
Intent i = getIntent();  
adapter=lv.getAdapter();// i get an exception here it's not working :(
list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("country&year");
adapter.addAll(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I can't convert an adapter to a list adapter

Comment: try the latest edited code and make sure you are getting data to your list from intent

Comment: I did exactly the same, program is crashing.

Comment: post the logcat error message and is the data coming to list from intent?

Comment: Please check the logcat error, it was to long so i had to post it as an answer!

Comment: I think the problem is I'm receiving before sending.