# How do I get all the selected list Items using Checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am using `Checkbox` with each and every list item, and now i would like to get name of all the selected list items on button click.

I have posted code of `Adapter` and `Activity` class as well, because later i have to show selected list items into another activity into ListView.

But for now i just want to see all the selected list items on button click

**Adapter:**

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        ....................

        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());           

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    // add into arraylist
                  selectedname.add(actorList.get(position).getName());
                }else{
                    // remove from arraylist
                    selectedname.remove(actorList.get(position).getName());
                }

            }
        });

        return v;

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code working fine for me so you can try this

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/select_btn"
    android:text="Select"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview"/>
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
</CheckBox>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

**Service**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Service implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;
private boolean selected;

public Service() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Service(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}
```

}

**ServiceAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<Service> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
Context context;

public ServiceAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Service> objects) {
    this.context= context;
    this.vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.actorList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(actorList.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isSelected = ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
            actorList.get(position).setSelected(isSelected);
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}


static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvName;
    public CheckBox checkBox;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return actorList.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return actorList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public ArrayList<Service> getSelectActorList(){
    ArrayList<Service> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<actorList.size();i++){
        if(actorList.get(i).isSelected())
            list.add(actorList.get(i));
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(new ServiceAdapter(this,sampleData()));

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.select_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Service> actorList = ((ServiceAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).getSelectActorList();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+actorList.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


public ArrayList<Service> sampleData(){
    ArrayList<Service> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        Service servic = new Service();
        servic.setName("Test"+i);
        dataList.add(servic);
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This may helps you.

```
ArrayList<String> selectedname  = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);          
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());  
       checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    // add into arraylist
                  selectedname.add(actorList.get(position).getName());
                }else{
                    // remove from arraylist
                    selectedname.remove(actorList.get(position).getName());
                }

            }
        });

        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvName; 
        public CheckBox checkBox;

    }
```

pass this selected `selectedname` `List` to another activity. on `Button` Click [pass List between Activity like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087198/passing-a-list-to-another-activity-in-android)

Comment: hey bro i am using your way, i just updated my code check above but still i don't know that how can i show all checked list of items on button click

Comment: can you pls check line In Button click   ArrayList<String> mselectedname = adapterObject.selectedname;

Comment: you can get  it from  ServiceAdapter adapterObject = new ServiceAdapter(your needed data pass here);

Comment: bro sorry but still not getting how do i show all selected items (into another activity as well) using click on button

Comment: See in your Button click first  you need to get Selected List item name, then you need to pass that list to second Activity which you needed, according that selected list item names, you can display list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087198/passing-a-list-to-another-activity-in-android

Comment: I have used System.out.println(selectedname.size()); to know the size of list item, but i don't know how do i get name of selected list items on button click, can you just show me this thing ?

Comment: ArrayList<String> mselectedname = adapterObject.selectedname;

Comment: System.out.println(mselectedname.size());

Answer (score 0):

create new arraylist and insert checkbox item into it

```
ArrayList<String> checkedSelection = new ArrayList<String>();


    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        // add into arraylist
                           checkedSelection.add(holder.checkBox.getText().toString());
                    }else{
                        // remove from arraylist
                         checkedSelection.remove(position);
                    }
                }
            });
```

and on button click send arraylist to another activity and load listview

Comment: below your this line holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());

Comment: check my updated code and let me know where i have to make changes

Comment: Instead of holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { You have to use                            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

Comment: i have updated my code, and how do i show list of items on button click

Comment: Either you can create a                                                                    static Arraylist<String> checkedSelection         in MainActivity 
then add or remove items in checkbox selected item as  MainActivity.checkedSelection.add() or    MainActivity.checkedSelection.remove()
and 
send to another activity in Intent as                                                            
toOtherActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("selected_list", checkedSelection);

or 

store it in shared preference and get that into another activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82804/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-oreo).

Answer (score 0):

For this do as below

Im MyAdapter create class level variable

```
public boolean[] checked;
```

and write onCheckedChanged event

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
   boolean isChecked) {
checked[position] = select.isChecked();
}
```

Now you can access boolean array as below

```
ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
boolean[] check =((MyAdapter) adapter).checked;
```

Now you can extract checked items

Hope this is useful

Edit:

Below the line

```
holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
```

Add listener like this

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
      boolean isChecked) {
      checked[position] = select.isChecked();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to maintain the `Checkbox` value in the `Actor` bean class

I have updated your `getView()` method of your adapter class.Have a look.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(actorList.get(position).getStatus());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                actorList.get(position).setStatus(isChecked);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Make sure to add the `getStatus()` and `setStatus(boolean)` to your bean class.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is:

Make a Model with a Boolean isChecked as a property

```
public Class CheckModel{
    String name;
    Boolean isChecked;

    public CheckModel(String name,Boolean isChecked){
        this.name = name;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    //setter and getter here

}
```

While adding the model into arraylist set isChecked to false as default

```
 arrayList.add(new CheckModel("title",false));
```

now in getView() function in Adapter change the isChecked property to true onChecked

`arrayList.get(position).setChecked(true);`

Lastly when you want name of all the Checked Items do this

```
for(int i = 0; i<arrayList.size;i++){
    if(arrayList.get(i).getisChecked()){
        //retreive the name
    }else{
        //ignore
    }
}
```